# Using pip or pip3 to install packages in Anaconda, Python, Jupyter

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I have always been under the belief that `pip` manages packages for one's python2, and `pip3` for one's python 3. On a JupyterHub server that I run, I have the habit of installing packages that our team uses as root. Doing `sudo -i` and then `pip3 install <package-name>`. Sometimes, this makes `import <package-name>` work from a python3 notebook in Jupyter. But often not. Then, if I instead do `pip` install , the package is accessible from notebooks (python3 ones, all of them) on the server. Why is this?

This is what I have:

```
~# which python 
/anaconda3/bin/python

~# which python3 
/anaconda3/bin/python3

~# which pip 
/anaconda3/bin/pip

~# which pip3 
/anaconda3/bin/pip3

~# which jupyter 
/anaconda3/bin/jupyter
```

Comment: for anaconda i think using `conda install <package name>` is better .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-difference-between-pip-and-pip3):

> pip3 always operates on the Python3 environment only, as pip2 does
>   with Python2. pip operates on whichever environment is appropriate to
>   the context. For example if you are in a Python3 venv, pip will
>   operate on the Python3 environment.